# Multiple Taxonomy Items for Separate URLs

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

Can anybody just let me know if this is possible for the start?

I have Custom Post Type "Recipes" and a Custom Taxonomy "Type", which consist of multiple items: breakfast, snack, lunch, dinner.

If I create a new recipe (example = "chicken-soup") and I assign it to multiple items (example  "lunch" and "dinner"), is it possible to have the next URL structure?

```
/recipes/lunch/chicken-soup
/recipes/dinner/chicken-soup
```

Right now, I can assign multiple items, but only primary item will have a URL - all other items will redirect to "primary".

If this is possible, how?

Thanx

Comment: Note that pages need to have a canonical authoritative URL or you run into major SEO penalties for having duplicate content. If those 2 URLs represent the same post with the same content then you'll be penalised in search rankings. That's why it redirects

Comment: They won't have the same content - I will assign a different template to each item for taxonomy with Elementor, but I need to solve the URL problem

Comment: hmmm if they do not have the same content, then why not create separate posts? You want separate URLs and separate content, so create separate posts and the problem goes away

Comment: Because post will have "same" content added to ACF - but Template will include some dynamical content which will change depending on taxonomy and ACF. Most important - totally different design. I have 10.000 posts - I really don't wanna duplicate them and assign again